# Classical analogue of the theorem of equivalence of the S-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, s-matrix-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

In quantum field theory there is a statement called the equivalence theorem of the S-matrix. S-matrix is invariant under reparametrization of the field. Is there in classical mechanics, the analogous statement, where S-matrix is replaced by the scattering map and the reparametrization - by the canonical transformations (symplectomorphisms).

My question can be formulated more directly without any reference to quantum mechanics (or QFT). Is the classical scattering map invariant under group of symplectomorphisms ?